# Programming a command button in Visio 2013 using VBA to open the layer properties window

Tags: vba, visio

This is an issue I have been trying to solve for some time now. I do not know VBA, I am still trying to learn. I have diagrams I created for work in Visio 2013 and the diagrams use layers. I am trying to code in a command button to open up the layer properties window for the active page the user clicks the button on. I have perused through the Microsoft documentations page for Visio but I cannot find out how to reference the layer properties window as an object and how to run it using VBA. This is what I have tried so far with different iterations;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Visio.Page.Layers.Properties("NameofPage").Run 
End Sub
```

I truly appreciate any help and guidance on this matter. I am not even sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in ms visio you can show layer properties window only for active page !

> Application.DoCmd (visCmdLayerSetupDlg)

Comment: Wow, how do you learn this? I cannot tell you enough how much I appreciate you sharing this. I don't have high enough rep to vote up for your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can find all ms visio docmd command in that article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/docmd-docmd-commands